# Verify that a point belongs to secp256r1

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptanalysis

I need to verify that the point in this public key

`04 11 95 23 03 f0 f1 f1 45 67 14 98 e4 39 80 ce 25 39 02 6e 72 34 fe 02 38 8a ea cc fb 3a 3d 4d dc d9 6d 3c fe 8b 55 bf ea c3 3a a1 59 13 54 b3 91 79 45 b7 3b 49 d9 0e 96 2a de 79 d3 49 dc 79 ca`

is in secp256r1. I already know the parameters $a$ and $b$ of the curve, but they are pretty big and they are hexadecimal. I've been trying to pass it to decimal, but I'm not getting it. Should I compute it in hexadecimal? I do also don't understand what are the coordinates of the public key. I mean, the public key is supposed to be a point with x-coordinate and the least important part of the y-coordinate, as the public key begins by 04, isn't it? I'm really sorry, but I'm confused about how to approach this.

**Note: I** saw some questions that were basically the same as mine, but the numbers were much smaller. I do also have PARI/GP to use.

**EDIT:** I tried with SageMath, and the result was

```
y = 98344895439910594971593461997930184197459096557735598026509132013917697767882
a = 115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853948
b = 41058363725152142129326129780047268409114441015993725554835256314039467401291
```

Then, I tried `y^2 == x^3 + a*x + b`, and it gave False, but I know beforehand that the point belongs to the curve. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Elliptic curve defined over the finite Field $\mathbb F_p$ means that all of the coordinates are elements of $\mathbb F_p$, i.e. in affine coordinates, let $P=(x,y)$ be a point then $x,y \in \mathbb F_p$. Actually, all of the arithmetic is done over $\mathbb F_p$

In the encoding

`04 11 95 23 03 f0 f1 f1 45 67 14 98 e4 39 80 ce 25 39 02 6e 72 34 fe 02 38 8a ea cc fb 3a 3d 4d dc d9 6d 3c fe 8b 55 bf ea c3 3a a1 59 13 54 b3 91 79 45 b7 3b 49 d9 0e 96 2a de 79 d3 49 dc 79 ca`

[The first byte defines the compression](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83465/18298) and `04` means there is no compression. So, after removing the `04`, the first half belongs to $x$ and the second half belongs to $y$ coordinate of the point.

You forgot to take $\bmod p$.

**With testing equality of both sides**

```
#Sagemath
x = Integer("0x11952303f0f1f145671498e43980ce2539026e7234fe02388aeaccfb3a3d4ddc")
y = Integer("0xd96d3cfe8b55bfeac33aa1591354b3917945b73b49d90e962ade79d349dc79ca")
a = Integer("0xFFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC")
b = Integer("0x5AC635D8AA3A93E7B3EBBD55769886BC651D06B0CC53B0F63BCE3C3E27D2604B")
p = Integer("0xFFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")

print(y^2 % p)
print( (x^3 + a * x + b) % p )
#or test with assert
assert(y^2 % p == (x^3 + a * x + b) % p)
```

outputs

```
107039974491263683037557989129009082794410266580376414531485756411379666775575
107039974491263683037557989129009082794410266580376414531485756411379666775575
```

Therefore it is a valid point on the curve.

**Using Curves on SageMath**

There is another way, and maybe easier on the SageMath. This method uses the Elliptic Curve construction and defining point on the curve.

```
#secp256r1
a = Integer("0xFFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC")
b = Integer("0x5AC635D8AA3A93E7B3EBBD55769886BC651D06B0CC53B0F63BCE3C3E27D2604B")
p = Integer("0xFFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")

K = GF(p)
E = EllipticCurve(K,[a,b])

x = Integer("0x11952303f0f1f145671498e43980ce2539026e7234fe02388aeaccfb3a3d4ddc")
y = Integer("0xd96d3cfe8b55bfeac33aa1591354b3917945b73b49d90e962ade79d349dc79ca")

P = E(x,y) ### try to set the point with the coordinates.
```

If the $P$ is not a point on the curve, you will get many errors

**Further notes**

In the next steps, you may want to add/double points. The elliptic curve uses special formulas for point addition. You may find them [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66296/18298), or use directly Sagemath, you can just use addition for point additions `P+Q` and `5*P`  for scalar multiplication where it is usually written as $[5]P = P + P + P + P +P$

**Representation of the point on infinity**

Points on the elliptic curve together with the point at infinity $\mathcal{O}$ form an abelian group under point addition law. For secp256r1;

$$E(\mathbb{F_p}) := \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{F}^2_p \mid y^2= x^3 + a\cdot x + b\} \cup \{\mathcal O\}$$

As we can see, the $\mathcal O$ has no representation on the affine coordinates, we magically add it to the group definition. While mathematically we can handle this, programmatically we need to represent it. If $b \neq 0 \bmod p$ then coordinate $(0,0)$ doesn't satisfy the curve equation therefore it is not on the curve, therefore it is a good choice for representation of $\mathcal O$ and usually selected this way. While working with the libraries always check that how the $\mathcal O$ is represented.

Comment: I had forgotten to take mod p. Thanks so much @kelalaka for all the help!!!

Comment: Now you can upvote, too. have fun.