# Verify that x, y coordinates given as hex string are valid points on an Elliptic Curve

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, dsa, test-vectors, secp256k1

Given the following information:

"curve": "P-256",

"qx": "729C51D177EBE2079A0FB7B0B3C2145159CF81EC61960E642A1744719AA9F913",

"qy": "8C36BCF51475016E614F8C7E0CB1B37C7EA65B4ECCF809852C9B2D0E438710BD"

The above coordinates are supposedly valid as per the test vector expected results:

"testPassed": true

I need to determine if the above public key coordinates are valid points on the curve or not.  I have tried converting the coordinates in python into ints with:

```
>>> x = int("7C96DFF02F55B876A2A885A920E9FB5E30C6E1A4061A62517FD5C936A16AD363", 16)
>>> y = int("301ABC6B82DF5B6B6D3E8D56D7660D83A6E4F55E321BD2E57A5AC4A6A683374E", 16)
```

And then plugged those integer values into both of the following formulas:

y^2 = X^3 + 7 (secp256k1)

y^2 = x^3 - 3x + b where b is 41058363725152142129326129780047268409114441015993725554835256314039467401291

In neither case did the formula indicate that the values were valid.

Would anybody happen to know how I could go about validating these coordinates?

Comment: For P256; it's the $y^2 \equiv x^3 - 3x + b \pmod p$ formula.  Did you remember to do the $\bmod p$ part?

Comment: Ah, I definitely had the formula wrong because I did leave out the mod p component.  How can I get that component out of the x, y coordinates?

Comment: If you know that you're checking a P256 curve, that gives you the $p$ value

Comment: Okay, I still end up getting the wrong value.  After conversion, I get the following x and y values:
x = 56353365848849265321159620645865428036014544177922197398856507648435978687331
y = 21758255182490996347272889474463336439598185139152900800520689763795259832142

This gives me a (y^2) % 256 = 196

and a (x^3 -3x + b) % 256 = 93

Is my constant b value wrong perhaps?

Comment: and with the first equation I get (x^3 + 7) %256 = 66

Comment: Why are you %256 doing? You're supposed to do %$p$.

Comment: Oh I assumed from the above comment that I was being dumb and that the p value would be the value of the curve (i.e. 256).  I guess I was still being dumb.  Could I get a link to the documentation that shows the p value?

Comment: @ponco the problem is this: the curve is not correct. It should be  secp256r1. The current point is not on the curve secp256k1 it is on the curve secp256r1.

Comment: Now I can call this dupe of this [Verify that a point belongs to secp256r1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/90154/18298)

Comment: Thank you Kelalaka, I did not realize I was on the wrong curve.  Much appreciated

Comment: A brief glance looks like yes, it will.  I haven't been able to test it as I got pulled into a meeting.  Won't get back to it for another hour or so.  I will mark it when I get back on it

Comment: Well, that was faster than expected.  Yup, works with the secp256r1 curve

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote you're supposed to check that
$y^2 = x^3 + ax + b \mod p$.

According to [this source](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/816.pdf).

$$p = 2^{256}-2^{224}+2^{192}+2^{96}-1$$

Notice that the $256$ refers to the bit size of $p$, and not to $p$ itself.

Comment: A commenter above pointed out that I am on the wrong curve, but I want to thank you for the link to that documentation, good knowledge for me to read through in general