# EC scalar multiplication with zero scalar

Tags: elliptic-curves

Is the elliptic curve scalar multiplication $[n]G$ defined if $n=0$?

I saw multiple software implementations with multiple results such that, $[0]G=0$ or $[0]G=G$.

This made me wonder, how can i compute $[0]G$ on 25519 curve, where G is the base point. $G=(9,14781619447589544791020593568409986887264606134616475288964881837755586237401).$

Also, is [n]$\mathcal{O}$ defined?

Comment: I think this covers your answers ; [Can you tell me why doing scalar multiplication of a point on a Elliptic curve over a finite field gets to a point at infinity?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68593/18298)

Comment: Also, where you see that $[0]G=0$  or $[0]G=G$, the later one is not correct.

Comment: $[n]\mathcal O$ is $\mathcal O$ for all $n$.

Comment: Use $[0]P = \mathcal{O}$ and multipl by $n$, $[0*n]P = [0]P = \mathcal{O}= [n]\mathcal{O}$

Comment: @kelalaka this is one of the software i used that gave me [0]=G.
https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/go_25519ecdh

Comment: File a bug on their site.

Comment: @kelalaka my mistake, the private key can't be zero in this software since it is used for ECDH. They always set the 254 bit, thats why i got a non zero result, which is [2^254]G.

Comment: You should always check the boundaries and see why they are not allowed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I saw multiple software implementations with multiple results such that, $[0]G=0$ or $[0]G=G$.

As stated in the comments, we define $[0]G = 0$, anything else is incorrect

I thought I'd outline why we define things we did.

What we want is to have $[a+b]G = [a]G + [b]G$ be true for all integers $a, b$, and all points $G$.

If it is true for all integers $b$, it must be true for $b=0$, hence we must have:

$$[a+0]G = [a]G + [0]G$$

This obviously simplifies to $[a]G = [a]G + [0]G$, and this is true only if $[0]G$ is the group identity, that is, only if $[0]G = 0$

Comment: Addition: in $[0]G = 0$, the left $0$ is an integer (or integer modulo $n$), But the right $0$ is not, and sometime is noted $\mathcal O$ to make the distinction. It's the neutral for point multiplication. It's called the point at infinity, and thus sometime is noted $\infty$. On Curve25519 [update: sorry Ed25519, which is _not_ the question's curve], the point at infinity has coordinates $(x,y)=(0,1)$.

Comment: @fgrieu why does the point at infinity has coordinates (,)=(0,1)?

Comment: @AshrafYassin: it doesn't; the point at infinity doesn't have any coordinates at all.  Now, some representations (that is, ways of writing down elliptic curve points as sequences of bits) may decide to denote the point-at-infinity as $(0, 1)$, however that's just a design decision (and is certainly is not universal)

Comment: There's some confusion here between Curve25519 which is a curve in Weierstrass form and Ed25519 which is a curve in Edwards form. On Ed25519 the identity point is $(0,1)$, but the base point is different from the one quoted in the question. On Curve22519 the point at infinity does not have an $(x,y)$ representation. It is important not to denote it with an actual $(x,y)$ value as some Weierstrass implementations will take these numbers and start doing computations on a related, but different curve.

Comment: @Daniel Shiu: thanks for the correction!