# How to calculate the exponential inverse in elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, modular-arithmetic

In Diffie-Hellman over $Z_p$, I know that if I choose a random $a$ in $Z_p$ and compute the modular inverse *mod p-1, not mod p*, then, with generator $g$ of my group, I can compute, for example, $(g^{ab})^{(a^{-1})} = g^{aa^{-1}b} = g^{b}$.

I am asking if a similar process is possible over elliptic curves? If I have a generator $P$ and I choose a random $a$ and compute $aP$. How do I do about calculating $a^{-1}$ such that $(aP)a^{-1} = P$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elliptic curve multiplication with negative factor](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31065/elliptic-curve-multiplication-with-negative-factor). AFAIK, both the question and answer will satisfy you.

Comment: You can use the extended euclidian algorithm to find k^-1.  See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36382/how-do-you-invert-an-ecdsa-multiplication-to-get-the-generator

Comment: Yes, answered thank you.

Comment: @mti2935 actually, if you look at the link I've provided one doesn't need that. $n-k$ is enough.